# Bar graph bleeding below y axis D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't figure out why my  elements are bleeding into the bottom padding. It is preventing me from having a  elements. I am sure it is something simple, it always is. I just can't figure out what's wrong. I have tried changing the  height and the scales, but it just changes things I don't want changed. I keep looking at tutorials on scales and I haven't found anything that seems off. If I get I have the project on codepen, here is the link: https://codepen.io/critchey/pen/YzEXPrP

Here is a screen shot to know what I am talking about:
[image]

Here is the javascript:

```
  //Mapping dataset to its x and y axes
  const xData = dataset.map(d => {
    let date = new Date(d[0]);
    return date;
  });
  
  const xDates = xData.map(d => {
    let dateFormatted = d.toLocaleString("default", {month: "short"}) + ' ' + d.getDate() + ', ' + d.getFullYear()
    return dateFormatted;
  });
  
  const yData = dataset.map(d => d[1]);
  //Variable for use inside D3
  const h = 400;
  const w = 800;
  const pad = 40;
  
  //Scales for the SVG element
  const xDateScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain([0, w])
                .range([pad, w - pad]);
  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, yData.length])
                .range([pad, w - pad]);
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(yData, (d) => d)])
                .range([h - pad, pad]);

  //Declaring the SVG element
  const svg = d3.select('#svg-container')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('width', w)
                .attr('height', h)
  
  //Declaring each bar
  svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(yData)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(i))
      .attr('y', (d, i) => yScale(d))
      .attr("width", w / (yData.length - pad * 2))
      .attr("height", (d, i) => d)
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .append('title')
      .text((d, i) => 'GDP: ' + d + ' | Date: ' + xDates[i])
 
  //Axes Declarations
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xDateScale);
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - pad / 2) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the correct value with the `height` attribute for your `rect`s

Just make the following change and it should work:

```js
.attr("height", (d, i) => yScale(0) - yScale(d))
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense.